# How to solve the @json Blade directive red underline on VSC?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

This variables are working perfectly, I wonder why are they with a red underline. Anyone knows how to correct this?

[image]

### **Error msg**

[image]

Comment: What does it say when you move your cursor onto those red lines? Share the error messages.

Comment: @dustinmwang2104 edited

Comment: Try installing this ext;
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since VSCode doesn't ship intellisense for `[blade]` template files in default, we need to install extra extensions for correct grammar checking and snippets support for `.blade.php` files. Here are some of them

1. [onecentlin.laravel-blade](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade) * works best for me
   [image: onecentlin.laravel-blade]
2. [cjhowe7.laravel-blade](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cjhowe7.laravel-blade)
   [image: cjhowe7.laravel-blade]

@Gass Hope this helps you.